# Verifying a binary tree in Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

So, I have a Prolog homework assignment. I'm trying my best not to break the honor code here, so I'm asking for hints rather than a full blown solution.

Let me reiterate: **Do not post code fragments please. You can post the name of built in predicates that might help me though**.

Anyhow, now that's out of the way, my assignment is to work with binary search trees. Here's a fact for a valid one I'm using:

```
tree(goodbst, [ [ [ [] , 1 , [] ] , 3 , [ [] , 4 , [] ] ], 10 ,[ [ [] , 12 , [] ], 15 ,[] ] ]).
```

My question is this: One of the things I have to code involves making sure that this is a valid tree (that is, that numbers in the left subtrees aren't greater than their roots, and numbers in right subtrees aren't less than their roots.)

Where would I start looking to find a solution? I've already got a predicate that ensures that a tree has a valid structure (follows the structure I described above) but I don't know how to start on this next predicate.

Comment: You probably won't need any built-ins except simple ones such as `=<`. This exercise is really about understanding recursion. (A simple, but hacky, solution would be to flatten the tree, then check whether the result is sorted.)

Comment: Just a couple of thoughts. You could try to express the solution a bit more in natural language (sort of a "pseudo Prolog") first, and solving a trivial case first upon which you can build a recursive definition. For example, "[ [], X, [] ] is a balanced, binary tree if X is an integer" or even "[] is a balanced, binary tree". (In Prolog, the "if" becomes `:-`.) You probably also want a predicate that tests whether all the elements in a given tree are `<` a given value `X`, and perhaps another to check if the values in a tree are `>=` a given value `X`.